# Nginx Redirect Issue

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to make a Ngix Rewrite Rule without success.

Basic file structure in the server is as follows:

```
base url/
├─ index.php
├─ users.php
├─ login.php
├─ register.php
```

- `example.com/users.php?&user-id=john` should redirect to `example.com/john`
- <strike>The above redirect should only work if `john` exists in the database, if it doesnt, give 404 error</strike> .
- navigating to example.com (base url) should show `index.php`
- `register.php` and `login.php` pages should work

I have tried the following:

- rewrite ^/(.*)$ /users.php?&user-id=$1 last;
  And `https://www.example.com/john` works, but any other request is passed to `users.php` (and i'm unable to navigate to `index.php`)
- `try_files $uri $uri /users.php?&user-id=$uri;`.In this case navigating to `https://www.example.com/john` shows an empty `users.php` file. Also navigating to other files in root directory, such as `index.php` shows `users.php` instead.

Here is the complete server block configuration (domain name has been replaced):

```
server {

    root /var/www/mydomain.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /users.php?&user-id=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Nginx gives what error?

Comment: How does nginx check if `john` exists in database? To me this redirect should be done in the application.

Comment: @Richard Smith, the error given was `try_files directive is duplicated`, i commented out  `#try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` and i was able to start the service successfully. However, `https://www.example.com/john`doesnt work, it just gives the empty `users.php`file. Also im unable to navigate to `index.php`

Comment: @Tero, i understand. in this case i'm looking for the redirect to work, regardless of if the user exists in the database, but still being able to navigate to other documents in the same root directory. Is it possible?

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question so that we will see the complete configuration.

Comment: @Tero, i added the information requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need a `location` block like this:

```
location ~ /(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /users.php?user-id=$1;
}
```

The `(.*)` will capture the part of URI after `/` to variable.

Then, the `try_files` first checks if files specified by `$uri` exist. If not, then request is passed to `users.php` where `user-id` argument is set to the captured contents from the `location`.

This means, URL `https://example.com/john` will be served from `/users.php?user-id=john`.

In your question you used `?&user-id` notation. That is incorrect. `?` specifies the start of query arguments section of URL, and `&` is separator between query arguments. Therefore, `?` is enough.

Another notice, you likely want to make a more exact match in the regular expression, for example `~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`. This matches only to alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I have added the specified `location` block, deleting the one containing my previous attempt, and after this the php files are not being executed. (Whenever i navigate to `https://example.com` i just download the file `index.php`)

Comment: If i remove the tilde `~`, next to location, the php files are correctly executed, however, navigating to `https://example.com/john` gives a 404 error. It doesn't appear to make any change to the URLs. Thanks for pointing out the `?&user-id` error.

Comment: Try placing this block after `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That did the trick. It is working exactly as intended now, been trying all day to make this work.